# UIAnimation cause button titleLabel disappear during animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, uianimation

I am committing this simple animation that cause a button to shrink to a width of 0:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                 delay: 0.0
                 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     [btnActionButton setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 10, 0, 55)];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 }];
```

Now the problem is that once the animation begins, the titleLabel of the button hides automatically... I made it sure using the slowAnimation mode of the simulator.

Is it possible that the label also shrinks with the frame during the animation, because it seems quite awkward if button title disappears in the beginning.

Thanks in advance.
Obaid

Comment: Yes it will also shrink because it is included in the button you are changing the frame with,

Answer (score 3):

It's due the width 0.

Use the below code.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
             delay: 0.0
             options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
             animations:^{
                 [btnActionButton setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 10, 50, 55)];
             }
             completion:^(BOOL finished){
             }];
```

in place of 50 give the width you want of button after animation.

Comment: your code will keep the button stay with a width of 50 pixels... instead of letting it disappear...

Answer (score 1):

```
          [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                      delay: 0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     [btnActionButton.titleLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(-64, btnActionButton.titleLabel.center.y)];
                     [btnDeleteButton setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 10, 128, 55)];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [btnActionButton setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 10, 0, 55)];
                     [btnActionButton.titleLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(0, btnActionButton.titleLabel.center.y)];
                 }];
```

This is how I managed to get it worked... Actually, I wanted to make the first button disappear and the 2nd button appear in a sliding fashion.

Comment: so this is the solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to animate the label too. I mean like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
             delay: 0.0
             options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
             animations:^{
                 [btnActionButton setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 10, 0, 55)];
                 [btnActionButton.titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(  0,  0, 0, 55)];
             }
             completion:^(BOOL finished){
             }];
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: This doesn't work too.... seems very stupid as it is a very common animation to hide a button in a way as i shrinks to one side.... :(